# Does characterAtIndex only have to be used for an NSString? And what is the main purpose of characterAtIndex?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string-length

I am writing an app on xcode and I am working on the code for the guess button so if the user enters a letter which is correct then the letter will appear in the location, length of the word in the label. I am using a characterAtIndex but an error continues to occure and I don't truly understand what the point of characterAtIndex is. This is my code so far.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *input;  //user input
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Guessesinc;  //number of incorrect guesses
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *word;  //the state of word as the user is guessing
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *rndw;  //the correct and unknown word 

- (IBAction)Guess;

- (IBAction)Guess
{
    bool match = NO;

    NSRange inputRange;
    char charinput = [input characterAtIndex: 0]; 

    for(int i = 0; i < self.rndw.length; i++)
    {
        char tempString = [self.rndw characterAtIndex: i];
        if (charinput ==tempString)
        {
            match = YES;
            inputRange = NSMakeRange(i, 1); //location, length
            self.word.text = [self.word.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange: inputRange withString: input];
        }
```

The input characterAtIndex does not work but I do not understand why. Is there a way to fix this issue. If this code did run this portion of the code should produce something like this --d-. So for example if the user entered a d and the correct word is code the word label should look like --d-. Would this code work for what it had to do??

Comment: You can only use methods that are declared for a given class. So yes, since `characterAtIndex` is a method of `NSString`, you can't use it on anything but an `NSString`. Why are you trying to call it on an uninitialized `NSRange`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer makes a few guesses:

1. The `input` text field contains the letter the user entered for the current guess.
2. The `word` label shows the current state of the exposed word as the user make their guesses.
3. `rndw` is the current word the user is trying to guess.

Given those assumptions about your code, your `Guess` method is close. It seems your biggest issue is the attempt to get the first letter from the `input` text field. You are trying to call `characterAtIndex:` on a `UITextField` instead of on the field's `text` property (which is an `NSString`). You are also attempting to replace a substring with a `UILabel`.

Here's your `Guess` method with a few little changes and cleanup. Also note that it is standard convention that variable and method names start with lowercase letters and class names start with uppercase letters.

```
- (IBAction)guess
{
    bool match = NO;

    unichar charinput = [self.input.text characterAtIndex:0]; 

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.rndw.length; i++)
    {
        char tempChar = [self.rndw characterAtIndex:i];
        if (charinput == tempChar)
        {
            match = YES;
            NSRange inputRange = NSMakeRange(i, 1); //location, length
            self.word.text = [self.word.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:inputRange withString:self.rndw.substringWithRange:inputRange];
        }
```

Comment: I messed up in the question above. My @property input is actually a UITextField because it is a textbox and not a label so would the suggest/improved code you wrote above still work even though the input is not a label?

Comment: Yes, no changes are needed. `UITextField` also has a `text` property. As long as you goal is to just look at the first character the user enters (or only allow them to enter one character), then the answer still works as-is. I did update the text of my answer to match the fact that `label` is a text field and not a label.

Comment: The `guess` method is an `IBAction`. So I'm assuming you've hooked that up to a button. I assume you let the user type in one letter and then they tap some button which results in `guess` being called. How you do all of that is up to you. But that's all beyond the scope of this question. If you have a new question, post a new question as needed. If you feel this question has been answered, you may indicate that by accepting which ever answer you feel best solved your issue.

Comment: I tried the code you recommended in Xcode. Unfortunately, this line does not work 'self.word.text = [self.word.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:inputRange withString:self.rndw.substringWithRange:inputRange];' There is an error appearing specifically for the .substringWithRange.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
char charinput = [input characterAtIndex: 0];
```

...is wrong.

Input is a `UILabel`. A `UILabel` is not an `NSString`. You probably want something like this:

```
NSString *inputString = self.input.text;
if (inputString.length == 0) {
  return; //Don't try to fetch a character from an empty string.
}
char charinput = [input characterAtIndex: 0];
```

However, even that doesn't make much sense because input is a UILabel, which is a display-only field, not an input field. If you're trying to collect text from the user you want a `UITextField` or `UITextView`. For gather a single line of text from the usr a `UITextField` is probably what you want.

It also isn't clear why you first try to fetch the character from index 0 in your input `UILabel`, and then later try to fetch characters from a string `self.rndw` that you never seem to initialize. I guess `rdnw` is the word the user is supposed to be guessing?

Comment: There is no use of `==` on `NSString` in the question's code.

Comment: Oh you're right. That's comparing characters. My mistake.

Comment: The less than ideal variable naming didn't help. :)